# String to enum mapping in Swift

Tags: swift, enums

I have an enum defined in Swift as follows:

```
 public enum Command:String {

   case first = "FirstCommand"
   case second = "SecondCommand"
   ...
   ...
   case last = "lastCommand"
 }
```

Now I receive a command dictionary from server and I extract the command string from it. The command string would typically be one of the raw values in Command enum or sometimes it could be a command outside the enum(example, new commands are introduced in future versions of client/server but client is still old). In this scenario, what is the way to use switch statement in Swift 3? How do I typecast the command string to enum and handle the unknown commands in default case of switch?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I'd attempt to create a `Command` with a raw value of the incoming string, and only use the `switch` if it succeeds. If it fails, then handle the unknown commands in another routine.

Like:

```
guard let command = Command(rawValue: incomingString) else {
    handleUnknownCommand(incomingString)
    return
}

switch command {
    case first:
        ...
}
```

Comment: A possible variant is `let command = Command(rawValue: incomingString) ?? .unknown` with a dedicated `case unknown`

Comment: Yes, as long as we can rely on the server not to send the string that maps to `.unknown`. Probably valuable to know which are legit commands, and which ones are unexpected.

Comment: You could define `case unknown = ""`, which makes it unlikely that the exact command string is sent :) – But it is just a suggestion, your solution is perfectly OK.

Comment: You talked me into it!

Comment: @JoshuaKaden: Actual it does no matter at all how the unknown case is defined, see below.

Comment: @MartinR It only matters if we're interested in making a distinction between `.unknown` as an actual value sent by the server, and an unexpected string. In one case, the server's value matches a value that we've coded for: It is legit. In the other case, it is a value that we haven't coded for: It's unexpected. This might be an important distinction, or it might not, depending on the context.

Comment: I see it like this: `.unknown` is meant as the value for all unknown commands. All strings from the server which are different from "firstCommand"..."lastCommand" are mapped to `.unknown` (and it does not matter if that unknown command is  "wot?" or happens to be the string "unknown")

Comment: It's a fine point, I admit. Can we just agree on "" and call it a day? :)

Answer (score 12):

A small variation of [Joshua's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44074929/1187415) is to add a dedicated
case to the enumeration which is used for all unknown commands:

```
public enum Command:String {

    case first = "FirstCommand"
    case second = "SecondCommand"
    // ...
    case last = "lastCommand"
    case unknown = "<unknownCommand>" 
}
```

Now you can use the (failable) initializer `Command(rawValue:)`
together with the nil-coalescing operator `??` to map the incoming string
to an enumeration value, with all unknown commands being mapped 
to `.unknown`:

```
let command = Command(rawValue: incomingString) ?? .unknown

switch command {
case .first:
    // Handle first command
case .second:
    // Handle second command
case .last:
    // Handle last command
case .unknown:
    // Handle unknown command
}
```

It does not matter which raw string is used for `case unknown`, so you 
could also define

```
case unknown = ""
```

if you like. The compiler verifies that the string is different from 
all other raw strings. And if the server happens to send that exact
string then it would be mapped to `.unknown`.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on how you're working with it, but you could do something like this:

```
func getCommand(for string: String) -> Command { 
    switch string {
        case Command.first.rawValue: return .first
        case Command.second.rawValue: return .second
        ...
        default: return .newCommand
     }
 }
```

I don't think it'd be possible to create new commands from the server in the return, but you could build a class with a `command` property that takes a `String` and works differently throughout the app.

Comment: for enums a default value in switch is not mandatory as the enum is already exaustive

Comment: @Md.IbrahimHassan In this case though the switch is a string, not an enum.

Comment: I was doing the same but I did not like writing Command.first.rawValue, Command.second.rawValue,...every time. I did accidentally upvote the answer though!

Answer (score 3):

To further expand the different ways you can solve this is by utilizing the  [CaseIterable](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/caseiterable) protocol.

```
public enum Command:String, CaseIterable {
    case first = "FirstCommand"
    case second = "SecondCommand"
    case last = "lastCommand"
    case unknown = "UnknownCommand"
    
    static func getCase(string:String) -> Command {
        return self.allCases.first{"\($0.rawValue)" == string} ?? .unknown
    }
}
```

The usage would be in this manner:

```
let textCommand = "SecondCommand"
let unknownCommand = "weirdCommand"

// What is the case label of the "textCommand"
print ("\(Command.getCase(string: textCommand))")

// The case label for our "unknownCommand" is
print ("\(Command.getCase(string: unknownCommand))")
```

You shift the usage of the null coalescing operator to the `Command` enum instead.
It looks a bit overengineered and it probably is. Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative structure, you can use optional case values and add a `nil` handler as the "default" value in the switch:

```
enum Command: String {
    case first = "a", second = "b", third = "c"
}

let command = Command(rawValue: "d")

switch command {
case .first?:
    print("first")
case .second?:
    print("second")
case .third?:
    print("third")
case nil:
    print("not found")
}
// prints "not found"
```